# c# get property of element in list with mixed types

Tags: c#, list, casting

i have a list with: Circle, Triangle, Rectangle in it

i want to edit the element with the id X but list[X].radius; is not available because it is a child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a mixed list and want to access members defined for the derived types, you have to cast to the derived type.

```
((Circle)list[index]).Radius = 10; // alternately use is or as if you're unsure
```

Of course, by the virtue of simply *having* a mixed list, you're saying that you generally do not care about the differences between the derived types, you're content with using the base polymorphically. If you find yourself in a different position, you should perhaps rethink your strategy for storing or consuming these elements.

Comment: this would crash in case at that index there is a Rectangle...

Comment: Of course it would. I was going to edit in the `as` or `is` variant, but being that someone else already has that covered and the topic is closed...

Answer (score 7):

You will have to detect the dynamic type of the element at runtime.

```
IShape value = list[x];
if(value is Circle)
{
   ((Circle)value).radius = 5;
}
```

You can also do something like:

```
Circle value = list[x] as Circle;
if(value != null)
{
   value.radius = 5;
}
```

This has the advantage of being a bit faster, since the cast is only done once.

Answer (score 0):

Typecast it:

```
((Circle)list[X]).Radius
```

Comment: this would crash in case at that index there is a Rectangle...